# How do I build an SQL query that discards repeating data?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple one-table SQLite3 database which stores the state of Internet reachability from my LAN's perspective.

```
CREATE TABLE inet_visibility (
    recid  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    type   INTEGER CHECK (type >= 0 AND type <= 2),   -- 0 = state change; 1 = periodic; 2 = other
    ts_new TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,                      -- entry created; UTC ISO8601
    ts_upd TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,                      -- entry updated; UTC ISO8601
    updcnt INTEGER NOT NULL,                          -- update tally
    state  INTEGER CHECK (state >= 0 AND state <= 2), -- 0 == unreachable; 1 = reachable; 2 = unknown
    byhost TEXT NOT NULL,                             -- IP of tester
    method TEXT NOT NULL,                             -- tool/process used to determine state
    note   TEXT DEFAULT ''                            -- optional note/comment
);
```

After several days of running, I've accumulated the following data:

```
recid       type        ts_new               ts_upd               updcnt      state       byhost        method      note
----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ----------
1           0           2019-05-20 10:31:48  2019-05-22 14:45:10  3106        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
2           0           2019-05-22 14:46:11  2019-05-23 07:41:52  981         0           192.168.1.47  ping
3           0           2019-05-23 07:42:52  2019-05-26 10:11:14  4438        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
4           0           2019-05-26 10:12:15  2019-05-26 10:12:15  0           1           192.168.1.47  ping
5           0           2019-05-26 10:13:24  2019-05-27 09:58:36  1415        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
6           0           2019-05-27 09:59:37  2019-05-27 09:59:37  0           1           192.168.1.47  ping
7           0           2019-05-27 10:00:49  2019-05-30 09:48:29  4277        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
8           0           2019-05-30 09:49:29  2019-05-30 09:49:29  0           1           192.168.1.47  ping
9           0           2019-05-30 09:50:34  2019-06-02 19:42:50  4877        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
10          0           2019-06-02 19:44:33  2019-06-02 19:44:33  0           0                         ping
11          0           2019-06-02 19:46:00  2019-06-03 10:32:44  881         1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
```

For the primary report, I'm only interested in the change of `state` at the earliest time. So for this report, I want the following data:

```
recid       type        ts_new               ts_upd               updcnt      state       byhost        method      note
----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ----------
1           0           2019-05-20 10:31:48  2019-05-22 14:45:10  3106        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
2           0           2019-05-22 14:46:11  2019-05-23 07:41:52  981         0           192.168.1.47  ping
3           0           2019-05-23 07:42:52  2019-05-26 10:11:14  4438        1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
10          0           2019-06-02 19:44:33  2019-06-02 19:44:33  0           0                         ping
11          0           2019-06-02 19:46:00  2019-06-03 10:32:44  881         1           192.168.1.47  heartbeat
```

The two key requirements to note from the above four-line extract are these:
    a) each `state` value alternates; and b) rec 3 (the earliest) is returned, not recs 4 through 9

I have no idea how to write a query to get these results.
`sqlite3 history.db 'select * from inet_visibility group by state order by ts_upd asc'`
... gives me only records 1 and 2.
`sqlite3 history.db 'select * from inet_visibility group by date(ts_upd),state order by ts_upd asc'`
... is a bit closer but too much data: I see records 5, 7, and 9.
I know both these queries are wrong; I was trying to home in on a solution and hit a wall (in my SQL skills).

In essence ... If you consider the data as an order list by ascending `ts_upd`, I only want the records where `state` changes relative to the previous record.

An aside: for this primary report, I only care about `recid`, `ts_upd`, and `state` - the rest of the columns can be ignored, if that matters.

Can someone offer a suggestion or a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use `lag()`:

```
select iv.*
from (select iv.*,
             lag(state) over (partition by byhost order by recid) as prev_state
      from inet_visibility iv
     ) iv
where prev_state is null or prev_state <> state;
```

This assumes that "previous row" is identified based on `recid`.  It also assumes that you only care about comparing `byhost` to see if `state` changed.

EDIT:

If you want `recid` 11, then you don't care about `byhost`.  Remove it from the `partition by`:

```
select iv.*
from (select iv.*,
             lag(state) over (order by recid) as prev_state
      from inet_visibility iv
     ) iv
where prev_state is null or prev_state <> state;
```

Comment: Ouch; that hurt my head. Definitely a learning moment - I'll need to dig into and understand `PARTITION BY` and `LAG()` - thank you! I added `order by ts_upd` at the end and it's almost perfect. (I'm missing `recid` 11.)